# How can I get the real size of image from the cropped image?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, android-capture

I crop the image with 600x600 pixels but when I get it to bitmap like this

```
if(requestCode==PIC_CROP&&resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    { 

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    //get the cropped bitmap
    Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
    //retrieve a reference to the ImageView
    }
```

my bitmap height and width are 300x300 pixels , why they are like that?

my crop method:

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 
    //indicate image type and Uri
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(outputFileUri, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop 
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    //indicate output X and Y
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 600);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 600);
    //retrieve data on return
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

and my activity result:

```
if(requestCode==PIC_CROP&&resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    { 

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    //get the cropped bitmap
    Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
    //retrieve a reference to the ImageView


    sourceFileUri="example.jpg"; 


    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
           out = new FileOutputStream(sourceFileUri);
           thePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
           try{
               out.close();
           } catch(Throwable ignore) {}
    }   
        }
```

and I check the size like this:

```
Bitmap  photo_Share = null ; 
        try { 
            photo_Share= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sourceFileUri,options);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        int imageHeight = photo_Share.getHeight();
        int imageWidth = photo_Share.getWidth();
```

But when I look in the gallery I see the my cropped image 600x600 but when I look it code (my purpose save it another place it is 300x300)
How can find the image with real size?

Comment: You have problem in cropping image.

Comment: my cropped image is 600x600 , I can see it in my gallery

Comment: Post more code, what are you doing. How you check, that it have width and height are 600px? We don't have enought details to help. Now, I think, that you have 300x300px image.

Comment: I edited my question please look